# Insert new table to exists csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am working with exists CSV file and in the CSV file there is a tables name like this :

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwfn3.png)

and I would like to add these two columns

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx4A4.png)

but I don't want to delete the existing CSV file's existing data, only append it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it maybe help you!

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_before.csv.csv')
df[['Sku','ExistsSN']]=None
df.to_csv('path_after.csv')
```

Comment: it works fantastic! the problem I have about 300 files to change the table name, the last issues that I want it to be in the second and third column, can you please help me with that?

Comment: @ברחיימוביץ no problem!
you just reorder column name. Append this code
`df = df[['UnitSn','Sku','ExistsSN','Income/Outgoing','TakenFromTicket','ToTicket','Delivered','Comment','EnterBy','Date']]`
after `df[['Sku','ExistsSN']]=None`
good luck

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a comma seperated Format, which you can also display in plain text(.txt File) opened by a text editor. When you trying to add those two empty columns you have to add for each row a comma for the position of the header column you want to add.

Example:

Header1,EmptyHeader2,Header3

value1,,value3

Note: For things like this might prefer to use Excel or other software for simply adding the column.
I hope I could help you. Good luck on this :)